# Get the value of multiple map (Map inside of map) from postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How can get the value of multiple key values (Map inside of map) from the postman

```
   {
       "message_key": { 
           "device_id": "12548652", 
           "message": "Y5482lsdfkOjEyNDUysdfsdfMTc1sdfOTM3MjU=", 
           "messageType": "Text" 
       } 
   }
```

Actually I want to bind value of `message_key` with domain to validate every properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer e.g:

**DTO:**

```
public @Data class MessageKey {

    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    private String deviceId;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("messageType")
    private String messageType;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public void test(@RequestBody Map<String, MessageKey> bodyParameters) {
    MessageKey messageKey = bodyParameters.get("message_key");
    System.out.println(messageKey);
}
```